# How do I set a default url for images[0] in Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, carrierwave

I have a standard image uploader using Carrierwave. I am also using Postgres. So this is what my migration looks like for adding images as JSON:

```
class AddImagesToListings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :listings, :images, :json
    remove_column :listings, :image
  end
end
```

I want to make images[0] always have some image, but it seems like the Carrierwave documentation only covers this for single file uploads. Right now, here is my default_url method:

```
def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default/" + ["default.jpg"].compact.join('_'))
end
```

This was working when I only had :image, but now it isn't. Is there any way to set a default for images[0] so that I get a valid images[0].url for every listing I have (despite whether or not a user adds an image to the listing)?

Answer (score 2):

As Carrierwave is not helping in this matter maybe you can use something like writing a helper or a callback for this job.
Here are some suggestions that you may like.

1. Write a helper

> ```
> module CarrierwaveHelper
>   def render_image_url(images, index)
>     return "Default.jpg" if index == 0
>     images[index].url
>   end
> end
> ```

and simply call render_image_url(images,0) in your view instead of images[0].url

2. write a callback in your model

> before_create :assign_default_image
>   or maybe you'll need before_update

```
def assign_default_image
  self.image[0] = "default.jpg"
end
```

Comment: Do you know if carrierwave has a built in feature to take care of this?